# Resources and admin panel are not available after installing

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I've installed Magento 2.1 Community Edition through composer (there was just an alert about some utility). I use Ubuntu 16.04, PHP 5.6, Apache2, MYSQL.

After installing I went to the admin panel but got just -

```
Not Found

The requested URL /admin_admin was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at magento.support.loc Port 80
```

Site settings in apache

`<Directory home/ivan/sites/magento>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>`

When I load my front page, I just see HTML markup and no one font or style loading. They are in not existing folders like

> http://magento.loc/pub/static/version1499045285/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css

There is no version1499045285 folder.

What i did wrong? Maybe i did not activate some Apache mods?

Comment: check in this url and that folder location http://magento.loc/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. there is such path, yes

Comment: yes i think. you are not activate mod_rewrite . enable apace rewrite and reinstall

Comment: @RamaChandran reistall magento? Or apache? How to test it? Maybe i can see if it's  activated or nor first?

Comment: First enable Apache and reinstall the magento it will work :)

Comment: @RamaChandran It is activated. When I enter "sudo a2enmod rewrite" I got "Module rewrite already enabled".

Comment: a2enmode is enable then . check apache config allow override is all for /var/www/html path

Comment: @RamaChandran i've set up permissions and it start working. Thank you.

Comment: Good news i placed the answer here. If it is correct please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on the server.

2 -After installation if css is not loading then please run deploy command from the root of magento

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

3- Set permission var pub/ static folder to 777

```
chmod -R 777 var pub/static
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue because of  `AllowOverride All` is not set and `sudo a2enmod rewrite` is not enable

```
<Directory home/ivan/sites/magento>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

**Deploy:**

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**Permission set:**

```
chmod -R 777 var pub/static
```

Comment: It's set. Rewrite mod enabled. Read the topic please.

Comment: I updated the answer